Primes of the form 2...21
I was wondering what properties could have these numbers:
$21, 221, 2221, 22221, ...$
At glance I thought this set would have infinitely many primes. Immediately I went to Python and I realized that from $21$ to $2...21$ (300 digits) the only prime is $2221$.
Therefore my next question was: is there at least one more prime? Or are them all composite?
This was my approach:
$$N=1+20\sum_{i=0}^k 10^i$$
If $$k \equiv 0 \bmod{3} \rightarrow N=21, 22221, ... $$ $N$ is divisible by $3$ and it's not a prime.
If not, I have no clue. But most of them end up being divisible by a small prime like $7$, $13$ or $19$.
It seems such a trivial quiestion but so hard to answer. Does anyone have an approach to the problem? Thank you.

Isn't the 16th one: $222,222,222,222,222,221$ prime?

It looks like the 98th, 119th, and 242nd are also prime...  What method of detecting primes did you use?

See also $,33\ldots 331$ in this question. $\ \ $

The first primes of this form : factordb , another two primes factordb

((1)) Your Python Script is wrong : It might be handling very large integers wrongly , having round-off errors during division , which might make Primes look like Composites. ((2)) In general , Arithmetic Progressions having at least 1 Prime might have infinite number of Primes.

@Prem This thumb rule is however only "reliable" , if we find one "large" prime.

As said , probably infinite many of those numbers are prime , but a proof is almost surely out of reach.

Instead of Python , you should use PARI/GP for this purpose.

Finally , why do you consider this to be trivial ? We have nothing better than to test the numbers (after sieving out cases with small factors). Such questions are not trivial at all.

Thank you for the answers! I did not know Python would fail with large integers. Appreciate them.

@FranciscoJavierMacielHennin See if python has a library which invokes thing like "gmp" , a library in itself which handles integers of arbitrary size.   https://gmplib.org/

See https://oeis.org/A084832

Thank you for the feedback! I will check this libraries
